# Satchmo like project in Java

Tags: java, e-commerce, satchmo

Is there a [satchmo](http://www.satchmoproject.com/) like project in Java?

EDIT

As for those trying to close the question, I did as requested and asked on server fault where [it](https://serverfault.com/questions/88669/satchmo-like-project-in-java) was not well received.

Comment: Why? Satchmo is not something you just deploy and let go, you have to build on top of it.  I'm asking from a development point of view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [Apach OFBiz](http://ofbiz.apache.org/), but it is huge clutchy.

For very fast development one could use pure-Javascript shopping cart library [simplecart.js](http://simplecartjs.com/)